# Transform path to namespace in a VS Code Snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am trying to create a VS code snippet that scaffolds the namespace based on the current folder in a project.

The current path provied by the `TM_DIRECTORY` variable could be something like this.

`/Users/bernhardrichter/GitHub/heatkeeper2000/src/HeatKeeper.Server/Mapping`

What I would like to end up with is `namespace HeatKeeper.Server.Mapping` based upon my root source folder being `src`

So I need to strip away everything before and including `src` so that we are left with `HeatKeeper.Server/Mapping`. And then I need to replace(transform) the `/` into `.` so that the final result is `HeatKeeper.Server.Mapping`.

Is it possible to do this in a single transform? If not is it possible to have multiple transforms?

This is what I have so far

`"namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*src.)(.*).*$/$2/}"`

This outputs `namespace HeatKeeper.Server/Mapping` which is almost what I want. I just need to replace all `/` with `.`

The problem is that I don't know where to put this transform.

The transform looks like this.

`"${TM_DIRECTORY/[\\/]/./g}"`

which gives me

`.Users.bernhardrichter.GitHub.heatkeeper2000.src.HeatKeeper.Server.Mapping`

I just don't know how to combine these two?

Answer (score 5):

See after the edit for a more general (not just the last two directories) answer.

---

Original answer:

Yes, you can do them in one snippet, you just need to separately capture the two directories after `src`.  Try:

```
  "namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*src\\/(.*)\\/(.*)$/$1.$2/}",
```

Then put a `period` between the two capture groups.  This regex assumes you always have a `src` directory preceding the two directories that you want.  If that isn't the case, this will work capturing the last two directories:

```
  "namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\/(.*)\\/(.*)$/$1.$2/}",
```

Note that the path separators "`/`" must be double-escaped.

**EDIT   ------------------------    see below   -----------------------------------------------**

For the more **general** case of some unknown number of directories after a specific directory, try this form:

```
"body": "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*src\\/(([^\\/]*)(\\/)?)|(\\/)([^\\/]*)/$2${3:+.}${5:+.}$5/g}",

// here for easier testing using the clipboard
"body": "${CLIPBOARD/.*src\\/(([^\\/]*)(\\/)?)|(\\/)([^\\/]*)/$2${3:+.}${5:+.}$5/g}",
```

Where `src` appears, put the last directory you do not **want**.  This works for 1 or more directories after `src` (in this case).

interestingly, it was the one folder case that was the trickiest.  That was solved by the extra conditional `${3:+.}` which means if there is a capture group 3, insert a `.`.

For the regex explanation, see [reg101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EXRTOR/2).  At that link you can see that a simpler substitution works except for the `one folder case`.  If you don't mind just backspacing over the that last `.` you could use the substitution `$2.$5` instead of `$2${3:+.}${5:+.}$5` I used above.

Finally, note that the above were designed to work with forward slash `/` path separators.  To modify it to use either back/forward slash separators, look at this (with `USERS` as the last unwanted directory):

```
   "body": "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*Users[\\/\\\\](([^\\/\\\\]*)([\\/\\\\])?)|([\\/\\\\])([^\\/\\\\]*)/$2${3:+.}${5:+.}$5/g}",
```

All forward slashes `\\/` get converted to the alternative forward and backslashes `[\\/\\\\]` where backslashes must appear as `\\\\` if you want to test for a literal `\`.  Yow.

[For the original question, just add `namespace` to the beginning.]

Comment: What if the number of directories after src is not fixed (eg could be 1 to 10), is there a way to make this generic?

Comment: @Alex I think I made it for the general 1 to infinity case.  Please test it and let me know.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I'm using it to set the package correctly for new Java classes.

Comment: Adapted version for generating Magento 2 class namespace: `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*app\\/code\\/(([^\\/]*)(\\/)?)|(\\/)([^\\/]*)/$2${3:+\\\\}${5:+\\\\}$5/g}`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161966)s solution didn't really work for me, it still contained the drive and all folders up to the filename or if i used the new `${RELATIVE_FILEPATH}` it still contained the filename
(i wanted the complete path without the workspace folder, so basically a project path inside a c#-project for example)
luckily with the new relative filepath variable  we can remove some of the complexity around the substitution and capture groups (`$3`, `$5` and such) and the RegEx itself.

tinkering with the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161966) and [an other post from @Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867810/11345448)
i came to the following solution:

```
"body": [
    "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^([^\\\\\\/]+)[\\\\\\/]|([^\\\\\\/]+)[\\\\\\/]|(?:[^\\\\\\/]+\\.[^\\\\\\/]+)/$1${2:+.}$2/g};",
    "",
    "internal ${1|enum,interface,sealed class,sealed record,record struct|} $TM_FILENAME_BASE",
    "{",
    "    $0",
    "}"
],
```

(for bit of testing see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WtcaxL/2) not 100% accurate to how VSCode seems to do it, but oh well)

... that still looks kinda atrocious, i know, but let me simplify it a bit and break it down

first, for simplicity, we don't use `\` and `/` as a separator, but `#` instead and remove the double escape the snippet needs. That lands us at:

- the RegEx: `^([^#]+)#|([^#]+)#|(?:[^#]+\.[^#]+)`
- the snippet substitution part: `$1${2:+.}$2`

further we can then break the RegEx up in its 3 alternatives `|`:

1. `^([^#]+)#`
2. `([^#]+)#`
3. `(?:[^#]+\.[^#]+)`

see how the first and second one are really similar ? thats because both, in essence, capture our folder parts, but the first one looks for the very first folder

- `^([^#]+)#` looks for the start of the string(`^`), then in a capture group (`( )`) for more then one non-`#` symbols ( `[^#]+` ) followed by exactly one `#`
  => with this we get the very first folder in capture group `$1` without any `#`'s
- `([^#]+)#` is exactly the same with out the start-of-string part
  => everything found here lands in capture group `$2` with out the separator `#`
- `(?:[^#]+\.[^#]+)` has a non-capturing capture-group (`(?: ... )`), that looks for more than one non-`#` symbol (`[^#]+`) followed by exactly one `.` (`\.`) followed again by more then one non-`#` symbol (`[^#]+`)
  => with this we capture the filename and its extension, even allowing extra `.` in the filename, and throw it away

lastly we use the format part of the transform ([see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar)) to stitch our output together:

- take the first capture group (`$1`), write it as is
- if the second capture group is not empty, write a dot (`${2:+.}`) (gets repeated for each time we match the group)
- add the second capture group (`$2`) (gets repeated for each time we match the group)

with this we don't have a dot (or multiple) at the end, removed the filename with extension (regardless of how many `.` it contained) and replaced all `#`(or in the original case any `\` or `/`) with a `.`

i think i put >24 hours of work in my free time into this (man do i hate RegEx), could i have spend them writing code instead ? sure, but sometimes there is fun following your perfectionism and tackling a challenge ;)