# Visual Studio Snippet: Can I use TM_FILENAME to get a namespace from RELATIVE_FILEPATH?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am toying with Visual Studio Snippets for a while now, and wonder if/how I can use TM_FILENAME to get a namespace from RELATIVE_FILEPATH. For example, I have:

RELATIVE_FILEPATH = src\model\RegisterModel.php

TM_FILENAME = RegisterModel.php

I want to strip the latter from the first, and the last \ as well, so I will end up with **src\model**

I can get it working if I use RegisterModel.php as a string, but not if I use TM_FILENAME as a variable. Is that even possible?

This is what works: ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(RegisterModel.php)//gi}

But I want something like this: ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(TM_FILENAME )//gi}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added it to the post!

Comment: Looks like you lost `$`, try `${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/${TM_FILENAME}//gi}`

Comment: I tried that already, doesn't work. Just to be sure, this is the line I use:

`"body": "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/${TM_FILENAME}//gi}",`

Comment: Strange thing is that this works, but that just strips out some of the characters in FILENAME that are also in FILEPATH: `${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/[${TM_FILENAME}]//gi}` with this result: `src\od\Rgsrod.php`

Comment: if you use HyperSnips extension you can program the snippet with JavaScript

Comment: I will have a look at Hypersnips. Sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you want:

```
"filepath": {
  "prefix": "rfp",
  "body": [
    "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(\\\\[^\\\\]*)$//i}",  // with lots of escapes
  ],
  "description": "directories of current file"
}
```

`${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/${TM_FILENAME}//gi}` will **not work** as according to the grammar only a `regex` can go into that `${TM_FILENAME}` spot in the transform.  See [snippet grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar).

Relevant part of the grammar: `transform   ::= '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options`

---

`${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/[${TM_FILENAME}]//gi}` results in:

`src\od\Rgsrod.php` because `[${TM_FILENAME}]` is treated as a regex (just a alternate list of those characters literally) and so each of those characters is removed from the `RELATIVE_FILEPATH`.

Comment: Thanks, man! Now I can get closer to my faux-PHPStorm vision.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was trying to create. This snippet creates a php class template with the proper class name and namespace from the file name and location.

So, snippet

```
  "php class": {
    "prefix": "_pclass",
    "body": "<?php\n\nnamespace app\\\\${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(\\\\[^\\\\]*)$//i};\n\nclass $TM_FILENAME_BASE{\n\n\tpublic function __construct(){}\n\n\tpublic function $1($2){\n\n\t\t$3\n\t}\n}",
    "description": "PHP class"
  }
```

called in `I:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\src\core\form\Field.php` creates

```
<?php

namespace app\src\core\form;

class Field{

    public function __construct(){}

    public function (){

        
    }
}
```

with the cursor on the method name. Saves me quite a bit of time, hope it's just as helpful for others.